# How to generate a treeview with group format? ( Letter that indicate the starting word )

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, treeview

I am developing an ASP.NET website and have a treeview to display countries which store in a MYSQL DB.

I am using this code to bind the data to treeview.

dt_Record is a datatable.

```
private void get_Countries()
    {
        try
        {
            dt_Record.Clear();
            dt_Record = objCommonMethods_Bll.Get_Countries();
            if (dt_Record.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt_Record.Rows)
                {
                    TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
                    node.Text = dr["name"].ToString();
                    node.Value = dr["Countries_id"].ToString();
                    tvCountries.Nodes.Add(node);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

So it displaying the countries like this

[image]

But I want to display countries like this. With a group letter to easily recognise the starting letter which can not be click.

[image]

Can I achieve above format? Then how to do that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using LINQ query but in my case I have user a datastructure for a model instead of from database.
But you can use database in your scenario.
Here is my code:

1) I have created a class to use it as table.

```
    public class Country
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

2) I have made a List with data filled, & in your case you are getting data from your database.

```
 List<Country> countriesList = new List<Country>()
                                        {
                                            new Country{Name="Algeria"},
                                            new Country{Name="Angola"},
                                            new Country{Name="Benin"},
                                            new Country{Name="Botswana"},
                                            new Country{Name="Burkina Faso"},
                                            new Country{Name="Burundi"},
                                            new Country{Name="Cameroon"},
                                            new Country{Name="Cape Verde"},
                                        };
```

3) and finally written the LINQ query to get the Grouped data as::

```
var temp = (from con in countriesList
                       group con by con.Name[0] into gr
                       select new
                       {
                           Key = gr.Key,
                           Value = gr.ToList()
                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your code but I am still unable to get through this..